# Dollar symbol in eval function php

Tags: php, html, web

I am trying to use the eval() function in PHP, but one of my variables (ppi) has a dollar symbol in it.

```html
$operation = "*";
$cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['cname']);
$to = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['prod']);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['desc']);
$ppi = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['ppi']);
$items = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['items']);
$total = mysqli_real_escape_string(eval('return '.$ppi.$operation.$items.';'))
```

Although simplified, the equivalent could be:

```html
$operation = "*";
$cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['cname']);
$to = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['prod']);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['desc']);
$ppi = '$10';
$items = '5';
$total = mysqli_real_escape_string(eval('return '.$ppi.$operation.$items.';'))
```

Whenever I try to run this code though, I always get a HTTP error 500.
Thank you in advanced,
Jack

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with eval?

Comment: **Never ever ever** try to execute user-supplied input as PHP code. You **will** get your site hacked that way. Whatever you're trying to accomplish using `eval()`, try to find another way.

Comment: rather have a switch (with the possible `$operations` as its cases). $ppi and $items are numbers anyway so it ends up as a simple calculation - you can avoid eval then.

Comment: `$total = intval(preg_replace('/[\D]*/', '', $ppi)) * intval($items);`

Comment: instead use another variable for monetary unit as $unit = 'Dollar' or simply '$' and let that $ppi be rate. Then you can simply do the mathematics with $ppi and any operator. Finally return the product concatenated with the unit.

Comment: @rickdenhaan, dont worry. This is just part of a much bigger application which will be transferred into an executable that will be run on users local machines. So if they try to do anything fancy, they will just be hacking themselves!

Comment: It's also about not providing an access point for hackers. Let's say I run your application as root on my Linux machine (or Administrator on my Windows machine) and a malicious hacker somehow gains access to a much more restricted user account on my computer. They could then use your application for privilege escalation and give themselves root/Administrator access to my entire computer, for example (not tested) by submitting a request where `ppi` is set to the string `exec("[...]"); // 1` where `[...]` is a list of bash or PowerShell commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work out the problem by expanding the string one by one:

```
$operation = "*";
$cname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['cname']);
$to = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['prod']);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['desc']);
$ppi = '$10';
$items = '5';

// New Bit:
$evalString = 'return ' . $ppi . $operation . $items . ';';
// $evalString = 'return $10*5;'

eval($evalString);
// This is equivalent of eval('return $10*5');
// Which errors as you can't have a variable begin with a number
```

---

Caveat: please take note of comments above: you'd be much better not using eval, casting correctly to ints() and evaluating other ways.

Comment: Adding a comment: if you DO have a variable `$10` you can access it with ${'10'}. But I doubt that's the case here, so I'm not adding to the answer!